# How to create a offset plugin for HTML5 video player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Am trying to create a offset plugin to play a portion of the video from full video in HTML5 video player, there is the plugin available for **video.js** 
[videojs-offset plugin](https://github.com/cladera/videojs-offset) , now am trying to convert this plugin to work with HTML5 player alone

Source of videojs offset plugin

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    var a = function(a) {
        var b;
        return this._offsetStart = a.start || 0, this._offsetEnd = a.end || 0, b = this.constructor, b.__super__ && b.__super__.__offsetInit || (b.__super__ = {
            __offsetInit: !0,
            duration: b.prototype.duration,
            currentTime: b.prototype.currentTime,
            bufferedPercent: b.prototype.bufferedPercent,
            remainingTime: b.prototype.remainingTime
        }, b.prototype.duration = function() {
            return this._offsetEnd > 0 ? this._offsetEnd - this._offsetStart : b.__super__.duration.apply(this, arguments) - this._offsetStart
        }, b.prototype.currentTime = function(a) {
            return void 0 !== a ? b.__super__.currentTime.call(this, a + this._offsetStart) - this._offsetStart : b.__super__.currentTime.apply(this, arguments) - this._offsetStart
        }, b.prototype.remainingTime = function() {
            var a = this.currentTime();
            return a < this._offsetStart && (a = 0), this.duration() - a
        }, b.prototype.startOffset = function() {
            return this._offsetStart
        }, b.prototype.endOffset = function() {
            return this._offsetEnd > 0 ? this._offsetEnd : this.duration()
        }), this.on("timeupdate", function() {
            var a = this.currentTime();
            0 > a && (this.currentTime(0), this.play()), this._offsetEnd > 0 && a > this._offsetEnd - this._offsetStart && (this.currentTime(this._offsetEnd - this._offsetStart), this.pause())
        }), this
    };
    a.VERSION = "0.0.0", window.vjsoffset = a, window.videojs.plugin("offset", a)
}).call(this);
```

What is the way i need to try this could work with HTML5 video player alone ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like something you could easily do with a minimal amount of code. I'd suggest writing something like this:

```js
function videoSegment(elementOrQuery, start, stop){
  
  var element = typeof elementOrQuery === 'string'
    ? document.querySelector(elementOrQuery) : elementOrQuery;
  
  element.currentTime = start;
  
  // While playing, check if time is within bounds
  element.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
    if(element.currentTime < start) element.currentTime = start;
    if(element.currentTime > stop) element.pause();
  });
  // When starting to play make sure its within bounds
  element.addEventListener('play', function(){
    if(element.duration > stop || element.duration < start) element.currentTime = start;
  });
  // When pausing, check if theres a loop and repeat or reset to beginning
  element.addEventListener('pause', function(){
    if(element.currentTime > stop) element.currentTime = start;
    if(element.loop) element.play();
  });
  
}

videoSegment('video', 2, 4);
```

```html
<video controls autoplay loop>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: i had already tried this, but you see it will buffer full video and play the portion of the video, but in the given plugin it only buffer the given offset only

Comment: Yeah but the plugin _has_ to buffer the entire video anyway. You will have to make mock-controls if you want to do this anyway, or buffer the video, cut the blob with JS and then insert that into an element, both ways are intensive and will simply put a strain on the browser.

Comment: i can't understand what you are saying can you explain further please ?

Comment: If the problem is that the entire video has to be buffered then you won't get around that using Javascript as javascript needs the entire video in order to cut it up and only display a portion of it. Something like that _has_ to be done server side. I think that cutting a video with javascript in a browser will be significantly slower than simply playing the provided file from a starting point to a finishing point. So the only viable way (that isn't horribly slow) is to use the code above and create your own `controls` instead of using the browsers standard controls.

Comment: Am not sure, but please check this link http://cladera.github.io/videojs-offset/, this done by pure javascript, it only play the offset from the client side only

Comment: Mate, the example provided _does not even contain controls_. This plugin works as expected: it does what my code does, it just hides the controls which make it look like it isn't buffering. Your video isn't getting cut into pieces right in the browser, it is simply playing from start and ending at finish, not playing the rest. Thats _exactly_ what my code does. Your complaint is about the buffer being shown, well, the only way around that is - just like your example does - displaying **your own, custom controls** that don't show buffering or the full length of the video.